# Oxtoby, measure and category, Vitali sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

In page 22 of that book (see picture below), Vitali set is described. And, the author remarks at the end of the page that Given a Vitali set $V$, then, $V=A \cup B$, where $B$ lacks the property of Baire.
Can any one explain, how can I conclude that $B$ lacks the property of Baire?
[image: Oxtoby: Pages 22,23]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxtoby writes, "Let $V=A\cup B$ be a partition of a Vitali set $V$ into a set $A$ of first category and a set $B$ of measure zero."

The set $A$, being of the first category, has the property of Baire. If $B$ also has the property of Baire, then $V=A\cup B$ would also have the property of Baire. However, in the preceding paragraph, it was shown that $V$ does not have the property of Baire.